# Wrapping defined types in classes - puppet

Tags: puppet

## My users.pp

```
class users::add
{
    define add_user ( $name, $comment, $home, $shell, $uid, $gid, $password)
    {


    # Create the user. This is where most of the magic happens.
    user { "$name":
    name => "$name",
    ensure => present,
    comment => "$comment",
    home => "$home",
    shell => "$shell",
    uid => "$uid",
    password => "$password",
    gid => "$gid"
    }


    file { "/home/$name/":
    ensure => directory,
    owner => $name,
    group => $gid,
    mode => 750,
    require => [User[$name]]
    }

    # And a place with the right permissions for the SSH related configs
    file { "/home/$name/.ssh":
    ensure => directory,
    owner => $name,
    group => $gid,
    mode => 700,
    require => File["/home/$name/"]
    }


    # Now make sure that the ssh key authorized files is around

    file { "/home/$name/.ssh/authorized_keys":
    ensure => present,
    owner => $name,
    group => $gid,
    mode => 600,
    require => file["/home/$name/.ssh"]
    }

  }

}
```

## My site.pp

```
   import "classes/*.pp"
    node default{
    include users::add
    add_user{"saga":name => "saga",comment => "Arun Sag",gid => "100",home => "/home/saga",password => '$1$passwordhash/',shell => "/bin/bash",uid => "70960",
    }
    }
```

As you can see, i have created a defined type and wrapped it inside a users:add class. I tried to call from site.pp, but when i tried to test this

sudo puppet master --compile=darkguard-dr.eglbp.corp.company.com --debug --verbose

```
debug: Using cached node for darkguard-dr.eglbp.corp.company.com                                                               
debug: importing '/etc/puppet/manifests/classes/users.pp' in environment production                                          
warning: Deprecation notice:  Resource references should now be capitalized on line 49 in file /etc/puppet/manifests/classes/
users.pp                                                                                                                     
err: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type add_user at /etc/puppet/manifests/s
ite.pp:5 on node darkguard-dr.eglbp.corp.company.com                                                                           
Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type add_user at
```

/etc/puppet/manifests/site.p
p:5 on node darkguard-dr.eglbp.corp.company.com

i get above error message. I am also planning to generate yaml using a ENC script. What must be the yaml format?

Answer (score 2):

Two things regarding your puppet code.

The define should be in it's own file (named add_user.pp, and located in the `<modulename>/manifests/` folder) , rather than in the class file.

Set the define up (change $name to $username, as $name is a reserved variable), and then add the same set of parameters as the define uses to the class. (which in your example would be `$modulepath/users/manifests/add.pp` to make it work with the autoloader)

If you change the class as follows:

```
class users::add( $u_name, $u_comment, $u_home, $u_shell, $u_uid, $u_gid, $u_password)
{
  users::add_user{ $u_name:
    $username => $u_name, 
    $comment  => $u_comment, 
    $home     => $u_home, 
    $shell    => $u_shell, 
    $uid      => $u_uid, 
    $gid      => $u_gid, 
    $password => $u_password,
  }
}
```

And change the site.pp to:

```
 import "classes/*.pp"
    node default{
      class { 'add_user': 
        username => "saga",
        comment => "Arun Sag",
        gid => "100",
        home => "/home/saga",
        password => '$1$passwordhash/',
        shell => "/bin/bash",
        uid => "70960",
      }
    }
```

For the yaml, something like this will do it, please refer to the [documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html) for more details:

```
---
classes:
  users::add:

parameters:
  name: some_name
  comment: some_comment
  home: home_value
  shell: /bin/sh
  uid: 3990
  gid: 3990
  password: superstrongpassword

environment:
  production
```

Comment: Quick question: The yaml file has parameters to create one username and password, is it possible to create multiple user accounts??

Comment: Yes, but since you can't use a define directly from an ENC, you'd have to rework things a little to make use of either [create_resources](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/2.7.9/function.html#createresources) or a hash of the users. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with that function.

Comment: While running 'sudo puppet agent --test --debug' "err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax e
rror at 'username'; expected '}' at /etc/puppet/manifests/classes ./users.pp:4 on node battleoffer-dr.eglbp.corp.company.com     
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run" The users.pp has the class definition. I have created add.pp at the module in /usr/share/puppet/modules/

Comment: I would even recommend splitting it out into its own module, instead of just a .pp file to be included.

Comment: Anyone looking to figure out how to use `hiera`, `create_resources` and a `defined type`, here's an article that might help: https://haani-niyaz.github.io/devops-journal/modify-files-with-puppet-using-file_line